# How to display inputstream in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, io, inputstream, jtextarea

This is to get stream from server.

```
BufferedReader fromserver = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
```

`jTextArea1` is the object.  How to display the input stream in `JTextArea` in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use [`JTextArea.append()` or `JTextArea.setText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
2. use [`JTextArea.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29)
3. there could be issue with [`Concurency in Swing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), have to invoke `XxxStream` or `XxxReader` from `Workers Thread`, use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) or `Runnable#Thread` (all output must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`),

Comment: #2, JTextArea(Reader, null) is definitely the way to go.  No need to read from the input line line-by-line yourself.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

> ```
> try {
>    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>    BufferedReader fromserver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
>    while ((thisLine = fromserver .readLine()) != null) { // while loop begins here
>      sb.append(thisLine);
>    } // end while 
>    jTextArea1.settext(sb.toString());
>  } // end try
>  catch (IOException e) {
>    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways.
First you can take the input in any String variable.

1. JTextArea(String text)
   you can use the above syntax while creating the object

or

1. or just simply create an object of it for ex  jTextArea1, and use method append(). ie,  jTextArea1.append(text);